# Flex box justify-content on main axis in center except for last flex item

Tags: css, flexbox

I have three flex items in my flex box. I want the first two centered and the last one to align all the way to the right along the main axis.

really basic overview:

```
<div class="flex flex-center">
  <div>flex item 1</div>
  <div>flex item 2</div>
  <div style="margin-left: auto;">flex item 3</div>
</div>
```

My CSS for the flex class is:

```
.flex {
  display: flex;

  &.flex-center {
    align-items: center;
  }
}
```

What happens when I use a `margin-left: auto;` is it pushes the first two flex items to the flex start of the main axis. I want the first two flex items centered, and the third item to align all the way to the right (end) of the main axis.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you just need to do a little math and use the `last-child` selector. Take a look at [my pen here](https://codepen.io/jpegzilla/pen/aRQPyz) and tell me if this is what you needed.

**EDIT:** I now think the best way to do this would be with some hidden spacer elements and the `flex-grow` property. [Example here](https://codepen.io/jpegzilla/pen/OBadRr).

Comment: Nope, your pen has 7 items and aligning vertical on the Y axis. I'm just looking for three items along the horizontal axis.

Comment: @randombits well, my bad. can you justify using absolute positioning in your use case? https://codepen.io/jpegzilla/pen/OBadRr

Comment: no, no absolute positioning unfortunately.

Comment: what do you think of this? https://codepen.io/jpegzilla/pen/OBadRr